# LINQ to SQL: if statement in select

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, select

in c# i want to return `IEnumerable<DataRow>` with column with name isedit

my type of innerResult is `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

but i have error

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

---

```
 innerResult = (from f in innerResult

                                   select new
                                   {

                                      isedit =  (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(((APS_WorkFlow_Activities).Contains(f.Field<Guid>("ActivityID")) ? false : true))
                                   });
```

Comment: You can simplify 
`Convert.ToBoolean(((APS_WorkFlow_Activities).Contains(f.Field<Guid>("ActivityID")) ? false : true)` to `!(APS_WorkFlow_Activities).Contains(f.Field<Guid>("ActivityID"))`

Comment: `innerResult` is declared as an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, but by saying `select new {...}` you are generating an anonymous type to return instead of a `DataRow`. When you say you "want to return the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` with column with name isedit", do you mean that you want to add a new column to each of the `DataRow` objects in the original?

Answer (score 0):

If  innerResult is anonymous type like the following, you can assign select result to the innerResult. Otherwise, you can't assign anonymous type to another type. You must declare new variable.

> var innerResult = new[] {new{isedit = default(bool)}}

Otherwise, declare new variable

> var innerResult2 = (from f in innerResult select new { isedit =
>   (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(((APS_WorkFlow_Activities).Contains(f.Field("ActivityID"))
>   ? false : true)) });